# Sort and rank list python and write back to MySQL using python

Tags: python, mysql-python

I'm reading values from MySQL using python then sorting a list. I need to then rank the list and write it back to MySQL. My code is

Get list

```
cursor.execute ("SELECT winnings, user, rank FROM round_lb WHERE r_id = 5")
round_test = cursor.fetchall()
```

returns

```
((90L, 70L, 0L), (17L, 1L, 0L), (25L, 78L, 0L))
```

Sort list (so the highest winnings column is first)

```
print sorted(round_test, reverse =True)
[(90L, 70L, 0L), (25L, 78L, 0L), (17L, 1L, 0L)]
```

I now want to assign a value to the rank field so 90 is rank1, 25 rank2 and 17 rank3 etc...

Which is where I get stuck.. does anyone know a simple way way to rank them in python... so I can then write them back to MySQL...

Comment: http://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/datastructures.html

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
>>> [row[:-1] + (rank,) for rank, row in enumerate(sorted(rows, reverse=True), start=1)]
    [(90L, 70L, 1), (25L, 78L, 2), (17L, 1L, 3)]
```

- `enumerate(rows, start=1)` returns returns a list of tuples of (rank, row), starting at `1`
- `row[:-1]` takes all items but last from the row (effectively striping the old rank)
- `row[:-1] + (rank,)` concatenates the first items of the row and a 1-tuple containing rank.

Why did you select the rank at all if you intended to replace it?

```
cursor.execute ("SELECT winnings, user FROM round_lb WHERE r_id = 5")
rows = cursor.fetchall()
for rank, (winnings, user) in enumerate(sorted(rows, reverse=True), start=1):
    params = (winnings, user, rank)
    cursor.execute("INSERT INTO round_lb (winnings, user, rank) VALUES (%s, %s, %s)", params)
```

Why not sort them in MySQL?

```
cursor.execute ("SELECT winnings, user FROM round_lb WHERE r_id = 5 ORDER BY winnings DESC")
rows = cursor.fetchall()
for rank, (winnings, user) in enumerate(rows, start=1):
    params = (winnings, user, rank)
    cursor.execute("INSERT INTO round_lb (winnings, user, rank) VALUES (%s, %s, %s)", params)
```

Comment: Hi Pavel, thanks for your help, I didn't think to sort them like that in MySQL, it seems like a much more elegant solution! Thanks again!

Answer (score 0):

If you just need a sequential ordering, you already have it in the position of the tuples in the list:

```
sorted_list = sorted(round_test, reverse =True)
# [(90L, 70L, 0L), (25L, 78L, 0L), (17L, 1L, 0L)]
ranked_list = []
for position, row in enumerate(sorted_list):
    ranked_list.append(tuple(row[0:2] + [position])) # replaces the 3rd row member
# ranked_list
# [(90L, 70L, 1), (25L, 78L, 2), (17L, 1L, 3)]
```